# FactoryGirl: omit attributes without creating an additional factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Sometimes `attributes_for` strategy returns unnecessary attributes, in other words, what if we need a couple of attributes, rather than to return all of them:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name { FFaker::Name.name }
    nickname { FFaker::Name.suffix }
    email { FFaker::Internet.email }

    factory :special_user do
      provider 'email'
      confirmed_at Time.now.strftime('%F %T')
    end

    trait :confirmation do
      current_password 'secret098'
      password 'secret567'
    end

    trait :valid do
      password_confirmation 'secret567'
    end

    trait :invalid do
      password_confirmation 'secret568'
    end
  end     
end
```

There is need to use factories with traits, but is that ever possible to return `current_password`, `password` and `password_confirmation` only? `attributes_for()` doesn't work with traits. Or maybe there is another way to do that?

Comment: I don't completey understand what you want to do or what's not working. For your example above, can you give your example `attributes_for` call, what it returns, and what you want it to return instead?  Traits in general won't fine with attributes_for, don't they? Using meaningful made up model names/attributes instead of foo/bar/baz (as you started to do with user/special_user) can also make the example more understandable.

Comment: it sounds like you want to access traits separately from the factory they are defined in, and this is not how they are designed to work.

Comment: @sevenseacat I know, but maybe there are other ways to filter atrributes somehow?

Comment: I guess you could make a factory that only includes the trait and nothing else, and ask for attributes_for that factory? In general, traits seem like they're only designed to be mixed into factories, not ever used indepdently. There might be some way to do it with FactoryGirl internal API.

Answer (score 3):

`attributes_for` will return you a hash of attributes, so you could just select the ones you want out of that hash.

eg.

```
FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user, :confirmation)
  .slice(:current_password, :password_confirmation)
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I could do that. Actually I was wondering whether that possible to do at factory level.